# Lodash: Transform array to string "FirstName, SecondFirstName and N more liked this"

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, lodash

Let's pretend there is an array of X elements.

X = 1: "Annie liked this"

X = 2: "John and Annie liked this"

X = 3: "Fred and John and 1 more liked this"

X = 4: "Jim and Fred and 2 more liked this"

X = 5: "Nick and Jim and 3 more liked this"

...

X = Y: "NewName and FirstName and Y-2 more liked this"

How to achieve this using Lodash?

I tried:

```
var say = _.rest(function(what, names) {
  return _.initial(names).join(', ') +
    (_.size(names) > 1 ? ', & ' : '') + _.last(names) + ' ' + what;
});

say('and ' + _.size(names) + ' more liked this', 'fred', 'barney', 'pebbles');
```

But it doesn't work as I want to achieve.

Comment: Have you tried anything? If yes, what and what did not work? If no, why have you not tried?

Comment: You should try yourself before asking.

Comment: What have you tried so far? And while you could use it, you don't need lodash for this...I don't think it would make your code any shorter. Also, I don't see any last names in your input.

Comment: Sorry, I've updated my question.. Yeah I spend a lot of time playing with `rest` helper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just check and join the parts in a single line.

```js
function getText(array) {
    return array.slice(0, 2).concat(array[2] ? array[2] + ' more' : []).join(' and ') + ' like this';
}

var array = [
        ['Annie'],
        ['John', 'Annie'],
        ['Fred', 'John', 1],
        ['Jim', 'Fred', 2],
        ['Nick', 'Jim', 3]
    ];

console.log(array.map(getText));
```

Answer (score 2):

I wrote it as a simple function:

```
function whoLiked(names){
    var s = names.length ? names[0] : 'Nobody';
    if(names.length>1) s+= ' and ' + names[1];
    if(names.length>2) s+= ' and ' + (names.length - 2) + ' more';
    return s + ' liked this';
}
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/kpzgyghh/